# Calculate Duration based on Next Row DateTime and GroupBy Hourly Data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I need to find the duration for each process in PostgreSQL.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "Process";
CREATE TABLE "Process" (
    "StartTime" TIMESTAMP,
    "State" VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
    "Remark" VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO public."Process"(
    "StartTime", "State","Remark")
    VALUES 
    ('2020-5-13 07:30:00','RUN',FALSE),
    ('2020-5-13 08:25:00','ASSIST', FALSE),
    ('2020-5-13 08:30:00','STOP', FALSE),
    ('2020-5-13 08:40:00','RUN', FALSE),
    ('2020-5-13 09:40:00','RUN', FALSE);
```

The duration is calculated based on next row "StartTime" minus current row "StartTime". This part is easy to find based on online resource. But I need to find the duration based on hourly cutoff data. Example every hour has his own process and duration.

Expected Output:

```
StartTime                NextRowStartTime     Hour                  State             Duration
'2020-5-13 07:30:00'  '2020-5-13 08:00:00'   '2020-5-13 07:00:00'   'RUN'             30
'2020-5-13 08:00:00'  '2020-5-13 08:25:00'   '2020-5-13 08:00:00'   'RUN'             25
'2020-5-13 08:25:00'  '2020-5-13 08:30:00'   '2020-5-13 08:00:00'   'ASSIST'          5
'2020-5-13 08:30:00'  '2020-5-13 08:40:00'   '2020-5-13 08:00:00'   'STOP'            10
'2020-5-13 08:40:00'  '2020-5-13 09:00:00'   '2020-5-13 08:00:00'   'RUN'             20
'2020-5-13 09:00:00'  '2020-5-13 09:40:00'   '2020-5-13 09:00:00'   'RUN'             40
```

As you can see from the output at '2020-5-13 07:30:00', it will become 2 result before 8am and after 8am.
Any idea to solve this? (can ignore the Remark column)

Comment: For SQL Solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732764/sql-split-total-time-by-time-intervals

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 0):

First,create another table for 24 hour integer

```
CREATE TABLE "HourGroup" (
    "H" INT UNIQUE NOT NULL
);   

INSERT INTO public."HourGroup"("H")
VALUES
('0'),('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5'),('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('10'),('11'),('12'),('13'),('14'),('15'),('16'),('17'),('18'),('19'),('20'),('21'),('22'),('23');
```

Then use LEAD() to get next row data

```
select
    "State",
    "Remark",
    "StartTime",
    LEAD("StartTime",1) over ( order by "StartTime") "EndAt"
from "Process"
```

Next join with another table

```
select A."State"
      ,"Remark"
      ,"StartTime"
      ,case when DATE_PART('hour',A."StartTime") = B."H" Then A."StartTime" ELSE ( DATE_TRUNC('day',A."StartTime")::timestamp + interval '1 hour'*(B."H")) END as  "HourStartTime"
      ,case when DATE_PART('hour',A."StartTime") = B."H" Then (case when B."H" = DATE_PART('hour',A."EndAt") Then "EndAt" ELSE  ( DATE_TRUNC('day',A."EndAt")::timestamp + interval '1 hour'*(B."H"+1)) END) ELSE (case when B."H" < DATE_PART('hour',A."EndAt") Then ( DATE_TRUNC('day',A."EndAt")::timestamp + interval '1 hour'*(B."H"+1)) ELSE "EndAt" END) END as  "HourEndTime"
 From "previousresult" A
 Join "HourGroup" B on "H" between DATE_PART('hour',"StartTime") and DATE_PART('hour',"EndAt")
```

Final query to calculate the duration.

```
select
    "State",
    "ProcessID",
    "Remark",
    "StartTime",
    "HourStartTime",
    "HourEndTime",
    SUM(("HourEndTime" - "HourStartTime")) as "Duration"
from cte2
group by "State","ProcessID","Remark","StartTime","HourStartTime","HourEndTime"
order by "StartTime"
```